# provide all (boost,.. whatever) libs to gcc in Freebsd and Ubuntu

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, freebsd

What commands are there to tell g++ to use all .so libs of a library like boost or opencv in a system?

I mean not to link it one by one manually like `g++ /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so ...`.
Forgot such command in ubuntu and don't know what is it in FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be you are looking for `pkg-config` ? If so, it's in ports in `devel`.
Usage: `pkg-config --libs --cflags libraryName`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `-L` and `-l` options with g++

Comment: just thinks it's better to use pkg-config in case some other system can have different include paths

Comment: Sure. Just wanted to let you know how it's done if you are using for example a library you wrote yourself which is not an installed package